# Group objects based on a id, and create a array of ojects

Tags: javascript, jquery

From an ajax request I get this array of objects:

```
0: Object
  group_id: 2
  group_name: "Name1"
  rez: 1
1: Object
  group_id: 2
  group_name: "Name1"
  rez: 3
2: Object
  group_id: 3
  group_name: "Name2"
  rez: 1
3: Object
  group_id: 3
  group_name: "Name2"
  rez: 2
```

I would like to group those values based on their `group_id`, and produce an array of objects which looks like this.

```
[{name: 'Name1', data: [1 ,3]}, {name: 'Name2', data: [1, 2]}]
```

Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: Looping over the response data, constructing each object, then adding them to an array should work.

Comment: Do you know if the group_ids will come in the correct order?

Comment: Yes they will come in order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the array will come in an correct order, and that `group_id` always results in the same `group_name`, you can generate the objects you want with this algorithm:

```
var out = []; 
for (var j in arr) {
  var obj = arr[j];

  var last = out[out.length-1];
  if (last != undefined && last.name == obj.group_name) {
    var data = last.data;
    data.push(obj.rez);

    out[out.length-1].data = data;
  } else {
    var newObj = {name: obj.group_name, data: [obj.rez]};
    out.push(newObj);
  }
}
```

Note: The array you recieve is given the variable name `arr` in this example.